# Rails - How to export nested resources to CSV in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, nested-resources

I am trying to export some data to CSV in Rails 4. I have two models: Excursions and Inscriptions. One excursion has many inscriptions and one inscription belongs to one excursion.

I have my nested routes defined this way:

```
  resources :excursions do
    resources :inscriptions
    get 'exportcsv' => 'excursions#download'
  end
```

So the behavior I am trying to achieve is: when I visit the route */excursions/1/exportcsv*, a CSV will be downloaded to my computer and it will contain all the inscriptions with excursion_id = 1 in CSV format.

In my excursion model I have defined self.to_csv:

```
  def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      self.inscriptions.each do |inscription|
        csv << inscription.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
```

And my excursion controller's method download:

```
  def download
    @excursion = Excursion.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @excursion.to_csv }
    end
  end
```

EDIT: When I go to a route like: /excursions/:id/exportcsv the server is throwing an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error. This error is easy to solve, but if I solve the RecordNotFound I get an ActionController::UnknownFormat in this line:

```
  def download
    @excursion = Excursion.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|  ########THIS LINE
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @excursion.to_csv }
    end
  end
```

What I am doing wrong? Maybe all this approach is not correct...

Comment: What is the issue? What is the output of your CSV? Are you having issue with the csv header columns or something else?

Comment: @Dharam I have updated the question. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would update the routes to the following:

```
resources :excursions do
  get 'download', on: :member, constraints: { format: /(html|csv)/ }
  resources :inscriptions
end
```

Also there is a bug in your model code. You are exporting `inscriptions` but are using `Excursion` column_names instead of `Inscription` column_names. Following is the updated model code.

```
class Excursion < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    inscription_column_names = Inscription.column_names

    csv << inscription_column_names

    self.inscriptions.each do |inscription|
      csv << inscription.attributes.values_at(*inscription_column_names)
    end
  end
end
```

Now try to access http://localhost:3000/excursions/:id/download.csv

Replace `:id` with an existing `Excursion` records id. If you still encounter `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error, then the problem could be that you are trying to access an `Excursion` that doesn't actually exist in the database.

Comment: I have updated the code but now the servers is throwing an: *Missing template excursions/download, application/download with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.*

Comment: Ok, I was missing the .csv extension. Anyway, now the server says that there is no method named to_csv: 
`undefined method 'to_csv' for #<Excursion:0x007efebfa93098> Did you mean? to_s`

Comment: Convert the class method `to_csv` to instance method `to_csv`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Ups, sorry! My fault :)